# Recreating database sequelizejs is slow

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When recreating the sequelizejs database with the sequelize.sync({ force: true }) command, then it takes around 3.5seconds before it is done.

Now when running tests this command has to run for each tests thus resulting in super slow tests.

Is there any way I can fix this so the tests run within 1 second?

Comment: What you  can do is make it recreate the database once before you run your tests, rather than recreating it before every single test. If your tests are contingent on the database being a blank slate each time, then there's not much you can do, other than optimize every single drop/create based on the test.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to optimise everything and maybe try to clear the data instead of dropping the tables.

Comment: Googler who come here might also be interested in calling `await sequelize.close();`, or else scripts hang for several seconds on PostgreSQL because it keeps the connection alive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289488/node-js-sequelize-do-not-close-automatically-when-the-script-done

Answer (score 1):

I decided to clean the tables instead of recreating them the whole time. This works faster and works for what I needed.

Comment: @mparnisari I would like to, but I stopped working with sequelize a long time ago after running in even more problems and removed all my code. Currently I am using bookshelfjs.org which suits everything I want to do, without running into bugs all the time.